# Show $\phi(a+b\sqrt2) = a-b\sqrt2$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$ with itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show $\phi(a+b\sqrt2) = a-b\sqrt2$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$ with itself.

proof: I already showed $\phi[(a_1 + b_1\sqrt2)(a_2 + b_2\sqrt2) ] = \phi(a_1 + b_1\sqrt2)\phi(a_2 + b_2\sqrt2)$ and that

$\phi[(a_1 + b_1\sqrt2)+ (a_2 + b_2\sqrt2) ] = \phi(a_1 + b_1\sqrt2)+ \phi(a_2 + b_2\sqrt2)$

so $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.

So now I need to show $\phi$ is surjective and injective.

$\phi$ is onto since for every $a+ b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$ , there is a $a-b\sqrt2 \in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)} $ such that $a+b\sqrt2 = \phi(a-b\sqrt2)$.

And $\phi$ is one to one, since by definition $ker\phi = $ {$a+b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q\sqrt2} : \phi(a + b\sqrt2) = 0 $}.

Then this happens when $a, b = 0$. So  $ker\phi = $ {$0+0\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q\sqrt2} : \phi(0 + 0\sqrt2) = 0 $}.

So since the $ker\phi$ is zero , then $\phi$ is injective.

Thus, $\phi$ is an isomorphism .

Can someone please verify , my approach in showing $\phi$ is surjective and injective function? Some feedback would really help. Thank you!

Comment: It is good. Maybe mention explicitly why $a-b\sqrt{2}=0$ forces $a=b=0$ ($\sqrt{2}$ is irrational).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty good!  Here are a couple changes I might suggest:

> $\phi$ is onto since for every $a+ b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$ , there is a $a-b\sqrt2 \in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)} $ such that $a+b\sqrt2 = \phi(a-b\sqrt2)$.

I would rephrase this as:

> $\phi$ is onto since for every $a+ b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)}$ , there is an $x \in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt2)} $ such that $a+b\sqrt2 = \phi(x)$, namely $x=a-b\sqrt{2}$.

The reason is that you shouldn't really say "there is a $a-b\sqrt{2}$"; when you say "there is a...", the next thing you say should be a new, undefined variable, not something that already has a defined value.  The way you write it is like saying "not all odd numbers are prime because there is a $9$ which is not prime".

> And $\phi$ is one to one, since by definition $ker\phi = $ {$a+b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q\sqrt2} : \phi(a + b\sqrt2) = 0 $}.
>
> Then this happens when $a, b = 0$.

In this part, you could give a bit more explanation.  *Why* does this only happen when $a,b=0$?